# Best OS agnostic way to implement doubly linked list in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, linked-list, c++14

I want to use doubly linked list in my c++ code which needs to be portable on all OS - windows, linux, MAC, android.
I read in internet that std::list would be able to represent a doubly linked list.

Have few questions like:
1) Is this OS agnostic ? Does it come under STL ?
2) Is there any advanced C++ mechanism of representing a doubly list ?

My linked list node looks like this:

```
struct LinkedListNode
{
   LInkedList* prev;
   LInkedList* next;
   struct data
   {
    //    vectorA[]
     //  vectorB[]
     // 2D vectors
     // strings
     // bool bflag
   }
}
```

Comment: `std::list<T>` is part of standard.

Comment: `std::list<T>` is part of the standard library, so it comes with any conformant C++ implementation. It does not have to be a double linked list (even though it is often implemented as one), but it has the same properties, and it'll probably be much more efficient / secure / whatever than a home-made implementation using manual allocations...

Comment: Actually linked lists are horribly inefficient on modern machines due to cache misses. Bjarne says don't use - normally a vector will be faster even if theoretically worse for Big O.

Answer (score 2):

> I read in internet that std::list would be able to represent a doubly linked list

That is exactly what std::list is.

> 1) Is this OS agnostic ?

The code that you have shown doesn't use any OS specific API, therefore it is OS agnostic.

> Does it come under STL ?

There is a double linked list in the STL. There is one in the C++ standard library as well: std::list. The API of std::list is same as that of the STL list. Former is based on the latter after all.

> 2) Is there any advanced C++ mechanism of representing a doubly list ?

There is std::list.